# Is it possible to check what data is present in the Jasper Page?

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I was wondering if i could be able to fetch the data in a Jasper Report. Once we have filled a Jasper Report i want to check on a Jasper Page what data is present. To the most i was able to go till Page but i was not able to find where the data is stored. Below is the code i have been trying to use:

```
JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(jasperDesign);
JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, map, con);
for (Iterator<JRPrintPage> i=jasperPrint.getPages().iterator(); i.hasNext();) 
        {
              JRPrintPage page = i.next();
             //How do i get the table data from this page now?
         }
```

please help..

Comment: @AlexK: Apparently the duplicate of this question was automatically deleted, because it had been sitting at zero score with no answers for over a year. As a gold badge holder, do you think this question should be reopened or also deleted?

Comment: @IlmariKaronen : Just because this question has been marked as duplicate users who might be knowing the answers are not able to provide there answers because it is marked as duplicate to a question which has no answers..Cheers to the gold badge moderators !!

Comment: @IlmariKaronen Reopened